# How to add custom command (action) button to exec bash in Toolbar for Android Studio/Intellij-idea?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I want to add a button to the Android Studio/Intellij-idea Toolbar to execute a custom command. For example:

`./gradlew --stop`

But when I click `Customize Menus and Toolbar...` only Android Studio Actions can be added:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to create an External Tool that runs your command.

[Here is an example on how to do it.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004311739-Run-terminal-command-from-external-tools-ANSWERED-)

And after that you will be able to add it to the toolbar

[image]

and run it with one click

[image]